# ImportError: cannot import name 'read_data_sets'

Tags: python, import, google-colaboratory

- I am trying to move my code **from my local machine** which uses python 3.6 under an anaconda environment **to Google Colab**,in order to make use of GPU.
- However,some commands are running localy,the same commands don't run in Colab,despite the fact that I have installed all missing **modules**(everytime I face such an error)
- The problem comes at command `from dataloader import get_loader`,where it throws an error.
- It seems that dataloader has problem,because the same error occurs when I just do `import dataloader`
- I have installed with `pip` dataloader=2.0.0
- I have searched a lot but I can't figure out a solution.

Error Message:

```
ImportError:Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-1c19174cb2f4> in <module>()
----> 1 import dataloader.get_loader
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/dataloader/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from dataloader import read_data_sets
ImportError: cannot import name 'read_data_sets'
```

Comment: if you have own file with name `dataloader.py` then it imports your file instead of module and it can't find `read_data_sets` in your file.

Comment: Yeah,that's it.It was my mistake.I forgot that this file is in the same directory and I thought that it was a module.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your own file with the name dataloader you will need to rename it.
for example:
from dataloader12 import build_augmenter works but dataloader does not work.